# How to get output and give input from/to batch file using java

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, process, runtime

how do i get output from a batch file, but also give input to a batch file?
My Q. is self-explanitory.
Like i made a small code to run a batch file:
    `Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("(my file)");`.
but now what?

Answer (score 0):

You can get input and output streams from the process using the corresponding getter methods.

Edit:

```
getInputStream()
```

and

```
getOutputStream()
```

Comment: im not on my ide right know, but i think then i can do this? `process.getOutputStream().println("text");` right?

Comment: Not directly. getOutputStream delivers just an instance of `OutputStream` - which does not have a println method. However, you can simply wrap the stream into something more suitable, like a `PrintStream`. This class should provide the necessary methods.